# AngularJS $scope reflection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there anyway to iterate all models within a scope with their names? I want to update each model according its name. These models are dynamically generated each time the page loads.

I want to implement something like the following:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span>The stock1 price is ng-model="stock1" </span>
<span>The stock2 price is ng-model="stock2" </span>
<span>The stock3 price is ng-model="stock3" </span>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 foreach(var v in $scope.variables)
{
v = GetValue(v.name);
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: What are your results when you run this? Any errors?  You can edit your question to add more information.  Someone will be more likely able to help you if you do.

Answer (score 1):

You have got it all wrong. `ng-model` is used with input, text-area and similar tags.

So you should have something like this :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input ng-model="stock1">
 <input ng-model="stock2">
 <input ng-model="stock3">
</div>
```

And as for your Javascript code, this is what you can try :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
    for(var i = 1; i < 3 ;i++)
       console.log($scope['stock'+i])  //Do anything else with your models
});
```

Comment: `<input>` has no closing tag or innerHTML. Also didn't put `ng-model` on `<input>` after telling OP they are doing it wrong

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry for the blind copy-paste and the absent-mindedness. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First. You need to define `$scope.stocks` as an array in your controller before you can start using it in your view.

```
$scope.stocks = [];
```

and use compile to generate your inputs

From the [Angular.js API reference on $compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile):

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

```
// Create input element
var input = angular.element('<div><input type="text" ng-model="stocks[' + $scope.inputCounter + ']"></div>');
// Compile the HTML and assign to scope
var compile = $compile(input)($scope);
```

working example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cosdbdej/2/)